# Preventing content from overflowing beyond scroll in a flexbox modal

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I created a modal using flexbox and it works great for small modals. The problem I'm having is that if the content height of the modal is too high, it will crop the modal and you can't scroll to the top or bottom of it. Below is a JS Fiddle illustrating this, and the main points are:

- Modal container is fixed position, flex and to center the content I have align-items: center, justify-content center. overflow-y is set to scroll.
- I've set the modal content to a height of 2000px to illustrate that you can't scroll to the text.

```
.modal-container{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000000aa;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal{
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
}

.modal-content{
  height: 2000px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/evrw81o3/

How can I get that content to display within the scroll boundaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `margin: auto` to your `.modal` class. See https://jsfiddle.net/89ja04v6/

```css
.modal{
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

The reason the text was not showing was that the content of the modal was overlapping the top of the screen, rather than starting at the top (as a non-flexed item would naturally appear). You can read a bit more about `flex` and `margin: auto` here: https://hackernoon.com/flexbox-s-best-kept-secret-bd3d892826b6